# Very slow JSON parsing using EVReflection depending on iOS device

Tags: json, swift, parsing, evo

I am **obtaining a json** object containing an array of objects. I am **willing to parse this json** using the lib `EVReflection`.

The operation takes a while, so I decided to monitorize the steps I'm taking, and realized **the parsing of the json can take up to 20** seconds depending on the device.

Using **iPhone SE / iOS 11.4** it takes **4 seconds** aprox.
Using **iPhone 5 / iOS 10.3 it** takes **20 seconds** aprox.

I am wondering if such variation is normal just depending on devices/OS.

Should I just use another lib or is there anything I can do to speed up the operation?

This is the code I'm using:

```
func getParkings(update: Bool) -> Observable<[ParkingEvo]> {
        if let x = parkings, !update {
            return Observable.just(x)
        } else {
            print("STEP 1: Calling API for parkings \(NSDate())")
            return RxAlamofire.string(.get, PARKINGS_URL, parameters: getParameters(), headers: nil)
                .map { self.parseParkings(json: $0) }
                .do(onNext: { self.storeParkings($0) })
        }
    }

private func parseParkings(json: String) -> [ParkingEvo]{
        print("STEP 2: Proceed to parse json \(NSDate())")
        let parkingsDTO = ParkingsDTO(json: json)
        print("STEP 3: ParkingsDTO created \(NSDate())")

        return parkingsDTO.items
    }
```

Between STEP2 and STEP3 there is the mentioned delay. Any idea on how to optimize this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think that for better performance you should not use library based on reflection.

Comment: I do not have any experience with `EVReflection`, but code written using the `Codable` protocol produces fully compiled code and works even nicer than typical reflection code I have seen (as you end up with nicely typed objects very quickly). In order to judge your timings you should post an example record of your JSON and the number of records you typically get.

Answer (score 0):

Try SwiftyJSON for parsing instead it is fast an easy check [Hacking with swift](https://hackingwithswift.com)

It is project 7 which you need to check

Answer (score 0):

For the record I ended up using [ObjectMapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) instead of EVReflection and spared 80% of the parsing time.